# Cocoa - 4.6 start a timer after play a little sound

Tags: cocoa, audio, timer

After I play a sound I need to start a timer, can anyone help me? I've written a little code with sound and time running at the same time

```
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"song", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundID);



    [sender setTitle:@"RUNNIG 2P" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    milliSecTimer1 =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(countUp1)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Sounds generally have non-zero duration. Do you mean to start the timer when you start the sound, or when the sound finishes?

Comment: By the way, you're leaking both the URL and the sound ID in that code.